# ts(1:47, frequency=12, start=c(1959, 2)) : What does the 2 in c() do?

Tags: r

Basic R question.
What does the 2 in c() do to generate the monthly time series data? Also, is frequency=12 a default which will always give me jan to dec columns?

```
ts(1:47, frequency=12, start=c(1959, 2))
```

Comment: "start: the time of the first observation. Either a single number or a vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit. See the examples for the use of the second form." https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html

Comment: had you seen  parameter of ts from r documentations

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand this

Comment: Did you look at the example?

Comment: `?ts` says it is "a vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit."

Comment: yes, i don't understand what a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit means. im very new to R and am just trying my best to understand. why would someone downvote a question like this, thats just mean.

Comment: i did not downvote your question. Nice explanation in the answer below.

Comment: I think it was down-voted by someone because they likely felt that the answer could be found by simply reading the help file and a minimum of effort is generally required in SO questions; however, the help file for `ts` seems not so clear to me so I have reversed it by adding an up-vote.

Answer (score 7):

### start argument

`?ts` says:

> start
>   the time of the first observation. Either a single number or a
>   vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit and a
>   (1-based) number of samples  into the time unit. See the examples for
>   the use of the second form.

In the example in the question 1959 is the year and 2 is the month (February) of the starting point.

1-based refers to the first month of the year being represented by 1, i.e. January is represented by 1, as opposed to January being represented by 0.  Thus January is represented by 1, February is represented by 2, ..., December is represented by 12 when specifying starting point.

### frequency argument

That same help page says with respect to `frequency` that:

> Values of 4 and 12 are assumed in (e.g.) print methods to imply a quarterly and 
>   monthly series respectively.

so using `frequency = 12` implies a monthly series.

### checking output

We can observe the above when we print it:

```
ts(1:47, frequency=12, start=c(1959, 2))
```

giving this monthly series which begins in February 1959:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1959       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
1960  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
1961  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
1962  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
```

Comment: so it specifies the starting month in the given starting year, thank you.